# React hooks - not updating consistently

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

So I'm semi-new to hooks. I want to run some basic validation. Running into a strange issue: when I run two hooks back-to-back, only the second of two hooks works.

```
const [validationTracking, setValidationTracking] = useState({});

const setValidation = (idx, field, value) => {
  const validationCopy = cloneDeep(validationTracking);
  if (!validationCopy[idx]) {
    validationCopy[idx] = {};
  }
  validationCopy[idx][field] = value;

  setValidationTracking(validationCopy);
};

const validateInputs = () => {
  partnerInfo.forEach((object, idx) => {
    if (!object['title']) {
      setValidation(idx, 'title', true);
    }
    if (!object['body']) {
      setValidation(idx, 'body', true);
    }
  });
};
```

In the above code `partnerInfo=[{title: '', body: ''}]`

The validation only gets triggered for body when I run `validateInputs`

If the array has more than one item, only the very last field will get its validation set to true `[{body: true}]`

The input above SHOULD set validationTracking to `[{title: true, body: true}]`but it seems to skip or override earlier items

I know this.setState() in class-based components is async. I'm wondering if something similar is happening here..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things to be aware of with the `useState` hook:

- the state change will not be immediately visible to your component logic until the next re-render of your component (and reevaluation of any closures)
- if multiple calls are made to a state hook's "setter" in a single render cycle, only the last state update will be collected and applied in the subsequent render cycle

The second point is more relevant to your question, given the `forEach` iteration in your code makes multiple calls to the `setValiadation` setter of your state hook. Because these are made in a single render cycle, only the last call to `setValiadation` will have an observable effect.

The usual way to address this is to gather all state changes into a single object, and apply those with a single call to your setter. You could take the following approach to achieve that:

```js
const [validationTracking, setValidationTracking] = useState({});

// Revised function
const updateValidation = (object, idx, field, value) => {
  const validationCopy = cloneDeep(object);
  if (!validationCopy[idx]) {
    validationCopy[idx] = {};
  }
  validationCopy[idx][field] = value;

  return validationCopy
};

const validateInputs = () => {

  // Call setter via a callback that transforms current state
  // into a new state object for the component
  setValidationTracking(state => {

    // Reduce partnerInfo array to a new state object
    return partnerInfo.reduce((acc, infoObject, idx) => {

      if (!infoObject['title']) {
        acc = updateValidation(acc, idx, 'title', true);
      }
      if (!infoObject['body']) {
        acc = updateValidation(acc, idx, 'body', true);
      }

      return acc;

    }, state);    

  });  
};
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you! This works. I appreciate the information.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand that `useState` hook works in a functional way. When you call it, it triggers a re-render of the component, passing the new state value to it. State values are immutable, they are not references to values that can change. This is why we say that a React function components acts as pure functions with respect to their props.

So when you call `setValidationTracking(validationCopy)` twice during a single update, you send two state updates that are computed using the current state for this iteration.

I.e: when the second loop calls `cloneDeep(validationTracking)`, `validationTracking` has not changed because the re-render triggered by the first loop has not happened and the state value is immutable any way.

To fix the problem you can instead pass a state updater function:

```js
setValidationTracking(currentValidationTracking => ({
  ...currentValidationTracking,
  [idx]: {
    ...(currentValidationTracking[idx] || {}),
    [field]: value
  }
}));
```